# What are the benefits of Java?

Tags: java

I always hear that programmers try to pick the right tool for the job.  I've never programmed in Java, so I was wondering What are its benefits?  Why is it so popular?  What should I use it for?

I just program recreationally.  Is there anything about it that makes it particularly fun??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think after 12 years or so, the "write once, run anywhere" mantra is *almost* true. Writing Java code pretty much isolates you from the platform dependent aspects of the systems on which you deploy it.

Comment: Don't all high-level languages mostly do that? or does Java really do it well?  I'm trying to decide whether it will be uniquely worthwhile to write in..

Comment: Not very many languages do that. A lot of languages are standardized so that you can often write code that will compile on most platforms, but not so that you can compile them once and run them on any platform.

Comment: Not all high level languages. Some do. Java does it well.

Comment: "Write once" is definitely a mantra, even a bromide. Being unable to abstract over type constructors, you have to be prepared to write the same things over and over again in subtly different ways.

Comment: Yes, lots of high level languages and platforms do it to some degree.  With Python, Perl, Ruby, or PHP it will work perfectly on every platform until you need a 3rd party lib that is difficult on your platform.  For .Net, Mono is a 85% solution.  Java is more like a 99.99% solution.

Comment: In answer to jsight, I have to say, I don't think Java is a 99.99 solution. It is a better solution in some cases, but you end up with exactly the same problem, if for instance, you want to use a different renderer, or you want to access some non-java system...

Comment: @aaron - Its true, if you want to access something that is inherently non-portable (os/platform specific), you end up with nonportable code.  Thats true no matter what you are coding in.  But you hit that a lot less in Java than other languages (how many C# apps P/Invoke vs. Java JNI?).

Comment: For "recreational" programming, the RWRA mantra is probably not applicable.

Comment: python runs anywhere too, so does ruby, and all interpreted languages I've heard of

Answer (score 11):

- Portability
- Incredible breadth of libraries
- Bottom-up security
- Performance
- Robustness

Answer (score 7):

Massive communities, the amount of help, libraries, IDE's, is huge (and thats a good thing).

Answer (score 7):

For a casual programmer Java can teach a lot about object-oriented programming, and encourage good programming habits in general, without the need to worry about as many of the "messy" details (pointers, memory management) as, say, C++.

It's also a bit easier to debug "catastrophic" errors.

Comment: these may be true, but other modern programming languages do better than java on these points.

Comment: @Ken Liu: Very true - so why not add some value to your comment by suggesting a few?

Answer (score 3):

Java is *really good* at integration - there are specifications and implementations for integrating with many kinds of systems that you're likely to run into in an "enterprise" environment.

It's not really a "fun" language relative to popular high-level languages.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be getting healthy answers, but you might also want to look at ["Why do people use Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213757/why-do-people-use-java)

Answer (score 2):

Cross platform is in my opinion the most relevant benefit.

The main goal of Java was to create a programming language that could run anywhere. The target was GUI apps. This however never happen because the environment was too slow at the beginning ( now it has been improved )  but it prove true in the server side where the cost of development reduced a lot because the product development can be done in PCs and the deployment in very expensive hardware.

It brought easy of development also, because it was designed to have C++ like syntax but running on a virtual platform to avoid platform specific code.  At first the penalty was the execution speed, because it was interpreted, but release after release the interpreters became more and more faster that even MS model its next generation of development after java and call it .net

**Additionally** You can have a read of the Java design goals [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Intro.doc2.html)

Comment: Java is not interpreted...And MS modelling .NET after java isn't exactly true, not at least in the last few years, MS has really taken the lead in innovation.

Comment: Actually Java is sort of interpreted. It's in the original white papers as one of the primary goals :P How that interpretation is done is dependent on the specific implementation, and JIT is one of the big optimizations.

Comment: Or rather, the platform-independent bytecode is interpreted.

Comment: Java is NOT interpreted??? .. And I guess you would say managed .NET apps are not interpreted either. Please read about  for CLR, CLI before. The fact it is compiled in and intermediate code does not imply it is not interpreted. http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Intro.doc2.html

Comment: .NET Code has never been interpreted. It is compiled from IL to native code, one method at a time. That is not interpretation. The method pointers are then modified to point at the compiled method, so that future calls always call the native code. Additionally, you can preJIT the entire assembly.

Comment: What he probably meant was that during execution it's not usually interpreted, which is also true for .NET apps. CLR and most JREs now JIT compile the Java bytecode into native code the first time it's executed.

Comment: With the introduction of the Hotspot VM, Java has the same JIT abilities that the CLR has always had. Yes, original Java was slow and interpreted, it is not now (Note your link is timestamped from 11 years ago).

Comment: Well that IS from MY point of view an INTERPRETER. From yours it is not,  that's fine. But one set of bytecodes are "interpreted" totally different in Windows, Linux, and MacOSX, that's the job of the JVM. If the interpreter creates assembly then is a terrific one! But still an interpreter.

Comment: Uh no, its a just in time compiler.

Comment: Interpreters NEVER generate native code.

Comment: Just to throw a bit of fun into the mix, Hotspot *does* actually interpret code the first time it runs it. That's more efficient for code which will only ever be run once (e.g. argument parsing). It quickly decides to compile it into native code where appropriate though.

Comment: Jonathan Holland: Python isn't interpreted either.  Its compiled to native code one instruction at a time. ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Holland - "With the introduction of Hotspot VM, , Java has the same JIT abilities that the CLR has always had." -- You do realize that Hotspot predates .net by YEARS, right?

Comment: Please don't feed the trolls.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a good language, but that is secondary to the importance of the standard library that comes with it. The jdk may not be the most elegant kit ever built, but it is extensive, powerful and reliable. Programming in Java the language is simple. Programming with appropriate reuse of the jdk is what it is all about.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add one point: Java keeps a good compatibility to earlier versions. That means, your Java-projects are compile and run in most cases without any problem on newer versions. That seems to be a little point, but this stability in API's and language helps to build a big community around Java, including good tool-support.

Others already mentioned other important points:

- good portability
- lot's of libraries for nearly anything
- easy debugging and easy to catch problems

Answer (score 1):

There are only two reasons to use Java:

- The Java Virtual Machine (Hotspot).
- The huge amount of available libraries and tools.

[There are other languages that run on the JVM and make better use of Java libraries than Java does, however.](http://scala-lang.org)

Answer (score 1):

After using Java for some time, I've come to the conclusion that it's fun to write in, limited in some very irritating ways, and it's performance is good though it seems that many programs are crippled by poor design.

I'm not sure if the latter is a function of Java, or an effect of Java.

In either case, in addition to all of the above stated benefits it's very useful for doing "net" related things. Treating resources with a simplified interface regardless of "where" the particular resource is, etc...

It is by no means a universal hammer.

Answer (score 1):

oop provides like encypsilation ,inheritance,polymorphism not available in traditional programing .oop is closer to real life presentation of the programming 
1. Relation ships can be representation using inheritance
2. Programme developement become easy due to increased modularity